# Android View.setRotation does not update view's size

Tags: android, textview, rotation

This is a TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/high_padding"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/draggable_view_component_main">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </FrameLayout>

    ...
</merge>
```

[image: screenshot1]

As you can see Im coding some kind of customizable TextView. But when I execute this:`textView.setRotation(45)`, I get this annoying result (image below). As it appears, the textview is not updating its width or height when rotated (I logged getWidth() and getHeight() inside onMeasure()).

I already found these questions:

- [TextView rotation keeps width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311484/textview-rotation-keeps-width-and-height)
- [Vertical TextView taking too much space in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059877/vertical-textview-taking-too-much-space-in-android/17061348#17061348)

But the answers only fix size when orientation is exactly 90 degrees (they just swap width and height)

So, is there a way to make the width and height dynamically fit the textView when rotated?

[image: screenshot 2]

Thanks in advance !

---

### EDIT

Based on @avalerio 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398000/avalerio), I found out how to calculate the width and height...

```
public class CustomEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    ...

    @Override
    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        super.setRotation(rotation);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int oldwidth = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();
        int oldheight = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingTop() - getCompoundPaddingBottom();
        int width = oldwidth;
        int height = oldheight;
        double angle = Math.toRadians(getRotation());
        ...
        // a bunch of boring calculations
        ...
        width += getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();
        height += getCompoundPaddingTop() + getCompoundPaddingBottom();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

The height and width seem correct, but the textView is still limited to its original bounds. Logging getHeight() and getMeasuredHeight() give the correct values, but how can I make textView draw in the new bounds ?

[image: screenshot3]